# Trying to understand a question and its supposed answer

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Question:
Suppose that the average income in the population in city X is 50,000 with a standard deviation of 10,000. Calculate the z-score for a person that earns less than 45,000, assuming that income is normally distributed.

My answer:
Z=(45000-50000)/10000=-0.5

Stated "correct" answer:
P(X<45000)=-0.5, thus using the Normal Table, P(z<-0.5)=.00621

I thought the "z-score" was just -0.5, aka how many std dev's the value was from the mean, which is one half std dev from the mean in the negative direction.

Also, the probability value with a z-score of -0.5 is 0.3085. Any help on where this "correct" answer came from?

Comment: Could you give us the exact quotes? The quotes you give do not make much sense, e.g. that the probability is -0.5.

Answer (score 1):

The $z$ transformation is $z = \tfrac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$, in your case mean $\mu = 50000$ and standard deviation is $\sigma = 10000$, so you calculated the $z$-score correctly. To get the probability that $X < 45000$, you calculate the probability from [standard normal cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), or use the tables. You correctly found that $\Pr(Z \le -0.5) = 0.35$. You are also right that $z$-score tells us how many standard deviation from the mean the value lies, so the closer it is to $0$, the probability should be closer to $0.5$, since $0$ is the median, so $0.00621$ does not sound like a right answer at all. I don't know where did the "correct" answer came from.

Comment: thank you for the confirmation. i am using saylor.org and that was the "correct" answer for a quiz.